# Is there any possibilities of performing bootstrap modals with django messages?

Tags: django, django-class-based-views

I am creating a accounting app, I was wondering if there is any possibilities of creating a bootstrap modal in django forms...I am using class based views for my app. Actually I need something like when the user submits any form they should not be redirected to any details view they should get a modal pop-up with success messages...

Is there any possibilities of performing this in django with class based views...Actually I am new to django thats why facing some basic difficulties, It will be real help for me if some one can help me out in this...'

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Yes... You can do it in `Javascript` with `AJAX`.

This link may help you!
[Ajax with Django](https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/08/29/how-to-work-with-ajax-request-with-django.html)